# How would you call a function that doesn't have a formula?

Tags: terminology, definition

What is the right name for a function that can't be described by a formula? I mean, I have $f(x) \to y$, but I can't explain how technically it gets the $y$.

I'm thinking about *non-describable*, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I would still call it a function. For the "simple" basic functions like $f(x)=x^3\sin(x)+\arctan(x)$ or stuff like that, I would use an extra adjective (if necessary) and refer to these as "elementary functions" (but note that this has a technical meaning).

Answer (score 1):

You can say that there is "no closed form" expression for it. If you know that the function is uniquely defined by some property or equation you cannot solve explicitly, e.g. if your $f(x)$ satisfy something like:
$$
2^{f(x)}+3^{f(x)} = x
$$
which cannot be solved explicitly (using e.g. elementary functions, or a finite number of operations) for $f(x)$, you can say that the your function is "implicitly defined by" that property.